# How to program static cells to take the height from storyboard while programming other cells to take height from code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a uitableview controller with STATIC cells in two sections.  I have adjusted the height of cells 0 & 1 in section 0 using storyboard.  However, I have used code to expand a date picker after a UIswitch is toggled and a cell is tapped in section 1.

My problem is that the code is overriding cells 0 and 1 in section 0.  How do I force those cells to take their height from storyboard?  If that is not possible, how would I code their height so that the cell expansion code does not override it?

Notes: I am new and don't fully understand the code that I used to make the expansion happen, so if I need to change that, let me know.  Code pasted below.

```
 var pickerVisible = false

// MARK: - COLLAPSABLE CELL

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2 {
        pickerVisible = !pickerVisible
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2 && toggle.isOn == false {
        return 0.0
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 3 {
        if toggle.isOn == false || pickerVisible == false {
            return 0.0
        }
        return 165.0
    }
    return 44.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   if indexPath.section == 0 {
      // set height for rows in section 0
   } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
      // set height for rows in section 1
   } else {
      // default height for your tableview cell
      return 44.0
   }        
}
```

- How do I force those cells to take their height from storyboard?

-> I think you don't really need this.

- How would I code their height so that the cell expansion code does not override it?

-> Its pretty easy to do what you want (sample code above)

Answer (score 0):

I have found another answer that really gets to the root of what my problem was -- how to program one cell to be an exact height and have all the other cells take the height from what is put together in storyboard.

The answer is instead of returning a number in heightForRowAt, you can do the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 170.0
    }
    // OTHERWISE, RETURN WHATEVER THE TABLEVIEW WANTS.
    return self.tableView.rowHeight
```